# Return Datetime.Day in persian culture by c#

Tags: c#, datetime, currentuiculture, persian-calendar

I intend to return the **day of the month** in **Persian culture**. I have already set the culture and it works well. the day which shows is in Persian calendar. But I need to check somewhere the exact day of the month,

for example today is 2018-2-3 and in Persian calendar is 1396-11-14,

```
var date = DateTime.Now
```

shows me the right Datetime in Persian calendar. But

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Day
```

***shows me 3 rather than 14.*** I need 14! I know I can change it to string and get the day but it make my code so dirty and I am not so interested in this way, because I used this in many parts of the program. 
Is there any way ?

Comment: As an aside, if you get frustrated with `DateTime`, my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library keeps the calendar system within its `LocalDate` and related types - so you really can have a single value that "knows" it's in the Persian calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to clarify a few things.

A `DateTime` instance is *always* on Gregorian calendar no matter what. Suprisingly, [it has a few constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) that takes `Calendar` as a parameter but I don't think this parameter effect *anything* about keeping it as a Gregorian  equivalent internally.

If you wanna get some parts of a DateTime in a *specific* calendar, you need to call that DateTime instance as a parameter of `GetXXX` methods on *that* calendar instance.

For examle;

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var persian = new PersianCalendar();
Console.WriteLine(persian.GetDayOfMonth(today)); // 14
```

Here a <kbd>[demonstration](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8oBOsq)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

you will try this code,.

```
 CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo("fa-Ir");
 info.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new PersianCalendar();          
 string day= "";
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
 day= DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
```

refer this link: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=persianculture

Comment: Persian CultureInfo already has the PersianCalendar as default calendar. There is no use assigning it again. Also, his default culture is already Persian as he said "DateTime.Now.ToString()" is printing the Persian date.